# Startup Disk Creator error

Tags: live-usb, startup-disk-creator

I get this error when trying to "Erase Disk" on Startup Disk Creator.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.AttributeError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 707, in _message_cb
    retval = candidate_method(self, *args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/share/usb-creator/usb-creator-helper", line 250, in Format
    partition = table.call_create_partition_sync(0, size, '0x0c', '', no_options, None)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'call_create_partition_sync'
```

Look at the color differences in the **Make Startup Disk** window. *Everything* below the "Erase Disk" button / "Disk to use" section is gray (buttons plus slider are disabled, so I can't change either of them).

1. What is this error message trying to say me?
2. What should I do to get rid of this error/problem? I need clear detailed instructions because I'm a newbie to the Ubuntu world!

Comment: Bugs in Ubuntu's core packages should be [reported on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usb-creator). As a workaround, you can try to erase/format the USB drive with the "Disks" program, before you use the Startup Disk Creator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Startup Disk Creator` tool is known to having some issues.
Use the `Disks` tool to create the Ubuntu installation media properly.

Open `Disks`, select Restore Disk Image from the menu on the top right of the application.
Choose the Ubuntu installation ISO file and the USB drive to write it to - then start restoring.

[image]

Comment: It is a good idea to include **screenshots** for the instructions. :)

Comment: Nice!! XD

I think this method could take USB-Creator out of the game.

Comment: Yes it's totally reliable.

Now that we are talking about it I think I will use it with Xenial.
A fresh install then all my setups and software I use and  a disk backup image and **boom** if I need to reinstall everything is done without internet connection required.

Comment: How do I find the Disks tool in 15.10?